# Error al implementacion de reestablecimiento de contraseñas con laravel y jetstream - ErrorException Undefined variable: request

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

[image: Error al implementar el reseteo de contraseñas con laravel y jetstream]

Hola compañeros, me he encontrado con este problema y la verdad no se a que se deba, segui al pie de la letra este proceso con la documentacion que nos da laravel sobre como implementar el reestablecimiento de la contraseña con los andamios de Jetstream, todo funciona bien hasta el punto en el que el usuario le llega el correo y el boton que le redirecciona al sistema para poder hacer el reestablecimiento marca ese error, las plantillas y todo lo demas siguen como cuando instale el proyecto de laravel no he modificado nada de lo que ofrece el andamio pero me marca ese error a alguien mas le ha pasado esto o si saben a que se deba?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas es la vista a la que se supone el usuario debe llegar para poder reestablecer su contraseña y es la vista que genera el error y este es el codigo de la ruta que nos da la documentacion para poder implementarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me alegro que hayas resuelto, pero para la próxima trata de no poner código en imágenes.

Comment: Ups, lo siento es que no suelo escribir aqui solo por que fue de verdad algo que no estaba entendiendo el por que! gracias .

Comment: No te preocupes, no hay problema. Es para futuras referencias. Piensa que es más fácil replicar tu fallo si podemos copiar tu código y por imágenes es más complicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar compañeros el error es por la ruta que viene en la documentacion hice esta modificacion

```
Route::get('/reset-password/{token}{email}', function (Request $request) {
return view('auth.reset-password', ['token' => $request->token,'email' => $request->email]);
```

})->middleware('guest')->name('password.reset');